# Laravel search by pure (non-backed) Enum

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, enums

I'm trying to perform a search in database by pure enum field:

```php
enum Enum1 {
    case Case1;
}

Model::query()->where('enum1', Enum1::Case1)->first()
```

And it's not working, causing an error `Error  Object of class Enum1 could not be converted to string.`

When I'm searching by backed enum it works:

```php
enum Enum2: int {
    case Case1 = 1;
}

Model::query()->where('enum2', Enum2::Case1)->first()
```

In `Model->casts` values are presented for both `Enum1` and `Enum2`.

I know, I can search by `Enum1::Case1->name`, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to set up suitable casting, if possible.
What is the easiest/correct way to handle this problem?

Comment: What would you expect Laravel to store in the database for an unbacked enum? BackedEnums were invented for this specific use case.

Comment: No, it knows! If I run `Model::query()->create(['enum1' => Enum1::Case1]);` it will store `Enum1::Case1->name` in database! So if I want to search by pure enum, I want to search by its value

Comment: There is no value... that is why you have BACKED... made it be `int` or `string` but it must convert it to string... by the way, instead of `Model::query()->create(`, you can directly do `Model::create(`

Comment: That was a mistake:) Of course, I want to search  by its name.

Comment: Check this out https://emekambah.medium.com/php-enum-and-use-cases-in-laravel-ac015cf181ad

Comment: Thanks for the link! Nice traits, but unfortunately it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think for you here is that MySQL does not have native support for Enum fields.

Eloquent in the where clause also expects to have the second argument as a string or some other 'common' data type as well.

Maybe at some point Laravel eloquent will support Enums but that is not the case for now I think.

I think there is nothing wrong with going with:

```
enum Enum2: int {
    case Case1 = 1;
}
```

This article [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php) actually talks about going to the DB with Enums, so have a read.

The point of Enums after all is to make the code easier to read, have the "Separation of concerns" principle in use and make the code more readable. We used constants and other tricks before they came out in PHP8

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm using PostgreSQL.

`Eloquent in the where clause also expects to have the second argument as a string or some other 'common' data type as well.`
No, it works with Backed Enums, as shown

Comment: Reading this article https://jelledev.com/how-to-use-php-enums-with-laravel-eloquent-models/

It states: "Note that Eloquent models only support backed enums - a backed enum always has an integer or string as backed type. In the code below it's the status string."

Which was more or less my point. Postgres does support them, but I am not sure how much that matters if the ORM level on top of it (Eloquent) doesn't.

You must somehow tell PHP and Eloquent what is your scalar value of you enum so that it can look it up the DB, hence the need for Backend Enums.

@trckster